# KnockoutJS css binding != true

Tags: knockout.js

My view model is returning a **true** value, and I'm trying to get my template to add CSS accordingly. The problem is, I can't find the syntax for a != true.

I have something like this:

```
<div data-bind="css: {'lw-touched': checked, 'lw-touch': !checked}"></div>
```

Which I thought would say, apply 'lw-touched' if checked === true, apply 'lw-touch' if checked === false. But that doesn't work :(. So I tried this:

```
<div data-bind="css: {'lw-touched': checked, 'lw-touch': checked !== true}"></div>
```

Which also didn't work.

I'm sure there is a way to do this! I just can't find it at the moment.

Comment: Damn it...just posted and solved it 30 seconds later. I'm leaving it cause someone else might have this problem... 

data-bind="css: {'lw-touched': checked, 'lw-touch': checked() !== true}">

Comment: Leave that as an answer to your question.

Comment: Actually you can use just `!checked()`. Whenever you are negating an expression you need to get the underlying value using the parenthesis.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I posted and solved it 30 seconds later :(.

I'm leaving it because someone else might have this same problem.

```
data-bind="css: {'lw-touched': checked, 'lw-touch': !checked()}">
```

Also I used the better syntax thanks to @MikaelÖstberg

I'm marking this as the answer so that I don't get more negative feedback :/

Comment: Would be great if you highlight that the brackets () made the difference. Nevermind, now my comment serves the purpose! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
data-bind="css: isPlaying() ? 'play' : 'pause'"
```

Consider to add the **()** at the binding field.

Comment: after applying this i got something strange:  class='0 1 2 3' in case of play value and class='0 1 2 3 4' for pause value. it seem like knockout took string.length value instead of string for class attribute. any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you ***g.breeze***, for your answer. I've been unsuccessfully trying to use the ternary operator on the **css** property, but never knew it could be set without the curly braces. One for the books!

```
data-bind="css: ifThisExpressionIsTrue() ? 'applyThisClass andAnother' : 'elseThisClass'"
```

You've bumped a two-year-old topic with your valuable answer.