# Why is KnockoutJS setting class attribute to "0 1 2 3 4 5 startsWith"?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following HTML segment:

```
<table class="answerGrid" data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <td>
            <button data-bind="click : $root.onAnswerClick, css: isSelected" type="button">
                <div data-bind="html: $data.text" style="height: 100%"></div>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I'm trying to do is dynamically set the `class` attribute of the `button` element via the `isSelected` computed function:

```
var Answer = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.id = "";
    self.text = "";
    self.selected = ko.observable(false);

    self.isSelected = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.selected() ? "selected-answer" : "answer";
    }, self);
};
```

The function is being executed, and I've checked that the text "answer" is returned due to the `Answer` not yet being selected. However, when I look at the outputted HTML, it looks like this:

```
<td>
    <button data-bind="click : $root.onAnswerClick, css: isSelected" type="button" class="0 1 2 3 4 5 startsWith">
        <div data-bind="html: $data.text" style="height: 100%">4-7 days</div>
    </button>
</td>
```

I'm totally confused as to why KO is setting the `class` attribute to "0 1 2 3 4 5 startsWith".

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Which KO version are you using? Can you repro your issue in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Version 2.1.0. Here is a repor for you: http://jsfiddle.net/j6Tta/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use a different approach:

```
<button data-bind="css: { 'answer': !selected(), 'selected-answer': selected() }" type="button">
    <span>Testing</span>
</button>​
```

So I'm not going to use the computed function at all, rather I'll directly access the `selected` property of the answer. I found this technique via this SO question:

[KnockoutJS css binding != true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320094/knockoutjs-css-binding-true)

Comment: I think, that can also solved by new knockout 2.2. "css binding can now attach programmatically-generated CSS class names to elements (previously, it was limited to toggling predefined CSS class names)": http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/10/29/knockout-2-2-0-released/

Comment: Excellent. May need to look into updating to 2.2 for the project I'm working on.